# Get selected time in javascript control

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm using the following JavaScript Control:

http://www.ama3.com/anytime/

How do I get the selected date in the control? So I can pass it to a postback page?
I tried finding it, but I'm just not very good at JavaScript :(

Which function do I have to call?

```
// Initialization
$(document).ready(function () {
    //alert("welcome");
    $("#DateTimeDemo").AnyTime_picker(
  { format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i: %E",
      formatUtcOffset: "%: (%@)",
      hideInput: true,
      placement: "inline"
  });

// Asp.net code
<input type="text" id="DateTimeDemo" style="background-color:Green;" />
```

I assume the code will be something like this:

```
 var x = getBlaBla();
```

Where x is something that I can use to pass to C# for postback info. I think I'll have to use JQuery to select the object I'll be taking the date out of.

Edit:
Okay I think I have to use something like this:

```
$("#DateTimeDemo").AnyTime_current(g, k);
```

what do the g and the k stand for? What do I have to pass?

Comment: Do you have code for your input tag and anytime picker? You should be able to get the selected value using your input id that your anytime is bound to.

Comment: An example of your code would be helpful (jsbin, jsfiddle, etc) or the actual page with the control. Most widgets like this usually set a hidden input field's value to the data the user chooses. You can attach an event handler to the input field or widget to set a variable based on the input's value.

Comment: I think this is it: `var x = $("#DateTimeDemo").val();
      alert(x);` I'll have to verify!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joe Johnson earlier commented, you will likely want to attach an event handler. With this method, whenever your input changes within the DateTimeDemo field, you can do something with that value.

```
$(function() {
    $("#DateTimeDemo").change(function() {
    var dt = $("#DateTimeDemo").val();
    alert(dt);
    // do something with dt. 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> I think I'll have to use JQuery to select the object

You never "have" to use jQuery, or any library. You can add an in–line listener like:

```
<select ... onchange="someFunc(this.value);" ...>
```

Where the logic for adding the listener is on the server, so no different to adding it at the client (but faster and more robust than any client–side method).

Or add it as a DOM property sometime after the element is created in the document (use the load event or a script at the bottom of the page):

```
document.getElementById('selectID').onchange = function(){someFunc(this.value);};
```

Or use addEventListener:

```
document.getElementById('selectID').addEventListener('change', function(){...}, false);
```

but include support for other browsers too (e.g. an addEvent function).